# Horizontal margin does not apply to the item in a ConstraintLayout vertically aligned by Flow

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-flow

I have a `ConstraintLayout` where I vertically align items via `Flow`.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
                    android:id="@+id/flow"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="item1,divider1,item2"
                    app:flow_wrapMode="none"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="16dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                    android:text="Item1" />

                <com.example.test.divider.Divider
                    android:id="@+id/divider1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="item2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="16dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                    android:text="Item2" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am trying to apply a horizontal margin only for the `divider1` item, however, the horizontal margin is ignored. Is there a way to apply a horizontal margin for an item in a `ConstraintLayout`, where items are aligned vertically by `Flow`?